# Excessive blank space after a graphic using R and kntir

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

The problem is the following:
[image]

I want to have the text from section 6 way closer to the graphics.

This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\emergencystretch=20pt  
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\begin{document}
<<results='markup',fig.keep='all', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
par(mfrow= c(2,2))
boxplot(a5,b5,col=c("azure4","azure3"),ylab="Calor latente(cal/gm)",
        xlab="Muestras",names=c("A","B"))
qqplot(a5,b5,ylab="Muestra B",xlab="Muestra A")
par(mfrow= c(1,1)) 
@
\section{Ejercicio 6}
blabla
\end{document}
```

I guess that the problem is that Latex still taking the whole graphic window size, even though I need just half of it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: No. The blank space is generated by R because you set space for FOUR plots with `par(mfrow= c(2,2))` but you fill with graphs only the first row, so the second row is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two plots use `par(mfrow= c(1,2))` (not `2,2`) and set the height accordingly if necessary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
<<results='markup',fig.keep='all',fig.height=4, message=F, warning=F,echo=F>>=
a5=c(1,2,3,5)
b5=c(1,2,3,5)
par(mfrow= c(1,2))
boxplot(a5,b5,col=c("azure4","azure3"),ylab="Calor latente(cal/gm)",
        xlab="Muestras",names=c("A","B"))
qqplot(a5,b5,ylab="Muestra B",xlab="Muestra A")
par(mfrow= c(1,1)) 
@
\section{Ejercicio 6}
blabla
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]